# What is the probability that that an item will pass the new process that's faulty?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A factory has implemented a new testing regime for all its goods before they leave the factory. It involves a three stage process. We will denote each stage as either  test $1, 2$ and $3$.

Once an item passes a test, it is removed from testing and is prepared to be shipped.

The factory knows that $90\%$ of their products are working before they test them.

[image]

(Note that the probabilities only apply when an item has not passed the previous test.)

> What is the probability that an item will pass the new process that's faulty?

---

Let,

$P_i$ denote "passes test $i$"

$W$ denote "item is working"

$\overline{W}$ denote "item is not working"

Therefore we have that,

$Pr(P_1|W) = 0.5$, $Pr(P_3|W) = 0.7$ and $Pr(P_3|W) = 0.85$

Similarly,

$Pr(P_1|\overline{W}) = 0.01$, $Pr(P_3|\overline{W}) = 0.04$, $Pr(P_3|\overline{W}) = 0.13$

And also,

$Pr(W) = 0.9$ and $Pr(\overline{W}) = 0.1$

> *This is my interpretation of this question*

We require $Pr(P_1 \overline{W} \cup P_2 \overline{W} \cup P_3 \overline{W})$

Since these events are disjoint we have that,

$Pr(P_1 \overline{W} \cup P_2 \overline{W} \cup P_3 \overline{W}) = Pr(P_1 \overline{W}) + Pr(P_2 \overline{W}) + Pr(P_3 \overline{W})$

Using the general multiplication rule,

$Pr(P_1 \overline{W}) + Pr(P_2 \overline{W}) + Pr(P_3 \overline{W}) = Pr(P_1|\overline{W})Pr(\overline{W}) + Pr(P_2|\overline{W})Pr(\overline{W}) + Pr(P_3|\overline{W})Pr(\overline{W})$

Hence,

$Pr(P_1|\overline{W})Pr(\overline{W}) + Pr(P_2|\overline{W})Pr(\overline{W}) + Pr(P_3|\overline{W})Pr(\overline{W}) = (0.01\times 0.10) + (0.04\times 0.10) + (0.13\times 0.10)$

Finally,

The probability that an item will pass the new process that's faulty is $0.018$ or $1.8\%$.

I have two questions;

1. Is my interpretation of the question "What is the probability that an item will pass the new process that's faulty?" correct and,
2. Does the line "probabilities only apply when it has passed the previous test" mean $Pr(P_i |W \cap P_{i-1})$ and $Pr(P_i |\overline{W} \cap P_{i-1})$ for $ i = 1, 2, 3$?

Comment: Is the probability that is being asked not zero? I understand question as: given faulty item, what is the probability that it will pass all the tests. But it cannot pass 1st test, and then it cannot pass any more. Note also that the eqents that you take as disjoint are not disjoint. To pass 2nd test, an item should pass the 1st one.

Comment: I tried adapting the above question from one in my textbook, I didn't want to explicitly ask the same question, I wanted to make sure I understand the process. I've added a few edits to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: I assert the idea that they're disjoint because if a test passes at a particular step in the process they are removed. That is, if we know that the item passes test 1, it couldn't have passed 2 or 3. Similarly, if it passes 3, it couldn't have passed 1 or 2.

Comment: But if item passed test 3, it passed tests 1 and 2.

Comment: I think I've confused you, sorry @NCh. I wrote "once an item passes a test, it is removed from testing and is prepared to be shipped."

Comment: But you also leave the phrase "(Note that the probabilities only apply when an item has passed the previous test.)". In this way the problem is not properly stated: should an item choose which test to pass? Or it is directed to the 1st test, shipped if passes and never goes to the 2nd one?

Comment: I've appended 'has not passed' to the line you quote. Should hopefully flow now.

Comment: Now there are no contradictions. And nevertheless, events are not disjoint. It seems that you are asked to find the probability $$P(P_1\cup P_2\cup P_3\mid \overline W)=P(P_1\mid \overline W)+P(\overline P_1\mid\overline W)P(P_2\mid\overline W\cap \overline P_1)+P(\overline P_1\mid\overline W)P(\overline P_2\mid\overline W\cap \overline P_1)P(P_3\mid\overline W\cap \overline P_1\cap \overline P_2)=0.01+0.99\times 0.04+0.99\times 0.96\times 0.13=0.173152$$
If you want to find the probability of intersection instead of conditional one, multiply it to $P(\overline W)=0.1$.

Comment: That would make much more sense! Thanks for your patience @NCh.